# How will I create an html page on the client machine

Tags: c#, url, client-server

For a campaign purpose i need to create some URL. When the user clicks on this URL, the html page need to be created on the client machine dynamically. And then when the user clicks on that page he'll be redirect to my own site. please let me know if you have better idea for this.

Comment: I have no idea what you meant in the question. Can you expand your thoughts a bit more

Comment: What do you mean by campaign purpose?

Comment: My suggestion is to add the exact tags to your question and elaborate it little more as V4Vendetta said. So that it'll be easy to answer you question.

Answer (score 2):

I don't understand the reason to do that.
Anyway you could *compile* a html page on client pc (you tagged your post C#, so I assumeyou're developing an app that lives on client pc), save that page in a file and then let it open with default browser.
I think the best way is you write your html page and publish it on a provider and let user pc visit it with browser... isn't it simpler?